# Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5, appharbor

I got the following error: "Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider." It only occur in AppHarbor server, not my local

I use .Net mvc4 and mysql

I have added MySql.Data, MySql.Data.Entity, MySql.Web to reference and set Copy Local = true. I also push bin folder to AppHarbor

This is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="fmcdatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.FMCEntityDataModel.csdl|res://*/Models.FMCEntityDataModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.FMCEntityDataModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=****;uid=****;port=3306;database=****&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
    <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="CustomMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="CustomMembershipProvider" type="FindMyCrushServer.Controllers.ControllerHelpers.CustomMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="fmcdatabaseEntities" applicationName="FindMyCrushServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Clear"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="FindMyCrushServer.Controllers.ControllerHelpers.CustomRoleProvider"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Any help is really really appreciated. Thank in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried using the NuGet packages?

- http://nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data
- http://nuget.org/packages/MySQL.Data.Entities

... they should make sure that right bits go where they are needed. You can use [NuGet package restore](http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/02/06/use-nuget-package-restore-to-avoid-pushing-packages-to-appharbor) to avoid pushing the package contents to AppHarbor.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll try it tommorow

Comment: But you don't provide the "answer". Why does this work? Will this solution work on production servers?

Comment: Instead of adding packages by hands, I used nuget to get them, and after that it works perfectly

Comment: @SandRock I think that suggesting the use of the official .NET dependency management system when a dependency fails to load is a good answer.

Comment: So let's all click buttons in the IDE without understanding any of the subsystems... Questioner, shall you not post a diff of your web.config and be all blessed by NuGet for offering us the magical miracle of ".NET dependency management".

Answer (score 5):

I just saw that the reason of this exception in my case were the differt versions between dll and the configuration entry.

So, sometimes the dll you actually have (either installed by nuget or other way) differs from the entry in the  node of the app.config.
This section, if not in app.config, can be also found under

> Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
>   and nearby folders.

Changing version in the entry to version of the dll solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me, my nuget doesnt add the necessary Dlls in the my project/bin. So copy pasting the all the missing DLLs from the package folder to bin folder solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I think the db provider factories in the web.config is the fix

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
        <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Comment: And obviously your connection string needs to include providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"